# Парсинг кода по частям

Tags: парсер, любой-язык

Мне необходим парсер который не парсит всю строку сразу, а возвращает итератор на токены.
Пример кода для парсинга:

```
l = [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
for elem in l:
    print(l)

UPDATE_SYNTAX() #здесь парсинг останавливаеться

SELECT a FROM l;
```

То мне надо чтобы парсер допарсил до UPDATE_SYNTAX, после чего бы вернул управление в главную программу, я бы в главной програме запустил функцию UPDATE_SYNTAX, она бы обновила правила парсинга, после чего парсинг должен продолжиться. Но для этого нужно чтобы парсер парсил только один токен за раз, а не сразу все.

P.S: UPDATE_SYNTAX может и изменять поведение уже определенного синтаксиса
так что необходимо именно обновлять парсер, а не как-то соовмещять синтаксис
P.P.S: Тип граматики не определен, то есть в UPDATE_SYNTAX может произойти какое угодно изменение синтаксиса.

Comment: Я думаю, вам нужно детерминировать "граничное условие" елемента синтаксиза (конца строки с операциями). Тогда при выполнении этого условия, будет включатся обработчик. Для части языков (бейсик vbs, иногда SQL) граничное условие - возврат каретки. Для с-образных языков это `;`

Comment: Вы имеете в виду [lexer hack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_lexer_hack)?

Comment: Ваша задача слишком обща. Конкретизируйте. И да, если у вас LL-грамматика, то построить поточный парсер проще простого.

Comment: @VladD тип граматики не определен.

Comment: @nick_n_a ок попытаюсь попробывать так

Comment: @AndrioSkur: Если тип грамматики не определён, то и решения нет, очевидно.

Comment: @VladD, в принципе, вроде в лиспе с их макросами чтения или nemerle что-то подобное реализовано?

Comment: @Grundy: Я не знаком с Немерле, а о применимости макросов судить не могу, пока задача не конкретизируется. В TeX'е, например, семантика может измениться в середина одного оператора.